# Clipboard setData ( html ) in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, copy, clipboard

Is there a way to set the data of the clipboard as html instead of plain text ? I know this is easely done in C# with :

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, (Object)temp);
```

But i'm looking for a javascript solution ( can include jquery etc ... )

Edit: this only needs to work for Internet Explorer

Comment: To do it cross browser, you need something like ZeroClipBoard, which uses Flash.

Comment: This only needs to work for ie ( edited my post )

Comment: The duplicate *does* have an answer for IE + HTML, which I found with a single Google search: http://stackoverflow.com/a/400403/70345